# Default style scope is being added in polymer 1.0

Tags: css-selectors, polymer, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom, paper-elements

Default scope is added instead of required class. Trying to change color in dropdown menu under in using conditional css in Polymer 1.

```
       <paper-item>
          <span class$ = {{setClass(item.no)}}> Polymer </span>
       </paper-item>
```

Comment: Could you please share your `setClass`  function and your depended class in `<style></style>`. Or you may use `style="color:{{setColor(item.no)}}"` and  in script `setColor(c){ return // conditional color  }`

Comment: yes, I edited it by adding the setClass function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example seems ok, just wrap your example double quotes. Beside you may try below:

```
<span style$ = "color:{{setClass(item.no)}};"> Polymer </span>


setClass(n) {
   if(n) return n <100 ? "blue":"red";
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, need to remove:`<template item-template>` inside `oe-combo`.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/mgbKyE?editors=1011)

Comment: oh thanks, as there are some other properties also like font-weight. That's why have to pass class name instead of only the color. I will try it with double quotes and let you know by tomorrow morning.

Comment: may I know the concept of how wrapping in double quotes will help. I mean what is the significance of double quotes here...

Comment: it's syntax only. As you use class="clasname". As above my example.

Comment: Ops I forget to warm you again. in <style> tag you need to declare:  paper-item > span {...} That's why I wanted to share your style code.

Comment: paper-item > span.blueClass

Comment: @ela Can u add your all codes again, I will illustrate the code at the code pen. It should work. just may need a small adjustment.

Comment: @ela Here is a working example. https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/bZXjmd?editors=1011

Comment: is it in Polymer 1 or in Polymer 2

Comment: @ela it's not important, but I also illustrated at polymer 1.x, just you have to do is remove:`<template item-template>` inside `oe-combo`.  here 1.x example: https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/mgbKyE?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks @Halank , it is working.  The syntax was correct. I just had to do some work around, based on the existing code. Thanks a lot for this great help.